# Python Inspection Error with custom type with Operator Overloads

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

Issue: I cannot seem to resolve some Python code inspection errors with type checking.

Background: In my particular application there is a "Galaxy" grid, each Sector of which is another grid of smaller positions.  In other words, you can view the map as either an entire global grid (say 100x100), or as a 10x10 grid of "Sectors" that make up the Galaxy where each Sector is itself a 10x10 grid of points.

I am creating a Coordinate class to manage these row/col pairs and I have defined **add** and **mul** on these objects.  Add combines two coordinates by performing vector addition on the x/y components, while Mul just scales both dimensions by an integer or float value.

I also have functions that can compose a pair of 10x10 (Galaxy + Sector) Coordinates into the global (100x100) coordinate space, and visa versa.

The math works, but the code inspector is unhappy and complains about type checks and I can't figure out what's going on.

Notably I cannot annotate the member functions of Coordinate with a "Coordinate" return type because it is claimed to be "unknown", presumably because the compiler is still processing the definition of the class.

Suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Python Type checker
Coordinate.py
Expected type 'Number', got 'Coordinate' instead
Type 'int' doesn't have expected attributes 'row', 'col'
Unresolved references
Coordinate.py
Unresolved attribute reference 'row' for class 'int'
Unresolved attribute reference 'col' for class 'int'
```

Here's the code:

```
import math


class Constants:
    GALAXY_SIZE = 10
    SECTOR_SIZE = 10


class Coordinate:
    def __init__(self, r=0, c=0):
        """ stores an integer row and column coordinate for a rectangular coordinate system.
            """
        self.row = r
        self.col = c

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Coord({self.row}, {self.col})'.format(self=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return '({self.row}, {self.col})'.format(self=self)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.row == other.row and self.col == other.col

    def __mul__(self, other):

        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Coordinate(self.row * other, self.col * other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __add__(self, other):

        if isinstance(other, Coordinate):
            return Coordinate(self.row + other.row, self.col + other.col)
        elif isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Coordinate(self.row + other, self.col + other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def restrict_to_bounds(self, low, high):
        self.row = apply_bound(self.row, low.row, high.row)
        self.col = apply_bound(self.col, low.col, high.col)
        return self


# helper math functions
def apply_bound(val, low, high):
    if val < low:
        val = low
    elif val > high:
        val = high
    return val


def convert_direction(direction):
    # convert map direction (0 degrees = up) to trigonometric angle (0 = +x direction, 90 = up)
    # assumes direction is in [0-360]
    # returns radians
    assert 0 <= direction <= 360, "invalid direction conversion"

    theta = 90 - direction
    if theta < 0:
        theta += 360

    return math.radians(theta)


def abs_ceil(x):
    # truncate value towards 
    if x < 0:
        x = math.floor(x)
    else:
        x = math.ceil(x)
    return x


def calc_move_offsets(direction, sectors):
    # while the user perceives the galaxy as Constants.GALAXY_SIZE sectors of Constants.SECTOR_SIZE, logically the
    # galaxy is a flat grid of Constants.GALAXY_SIZE * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE coordinates across, so we calculate moves
    # in global coordinates.
    # one sector is equivalent to exactly one Constants.SECTOR_SIZE of global coordinates.
    theta = convert_direction(direction)
    x = math.trunc(sectors * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE * math.cos(theta))
    y = -math.trunc(sectors * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE * math.sin(theta))

    return Coordinate(y, x)


def galsec_to_global(gal: Coordinate, sec: Coordinate) -> Coordinate:
    # convert galactic/sector coord pair to global coordinate
```

ERROR Expected type 'Number', got 'Coordinate' instead. This highlights "sec" on following line:

```
    return (gal * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE) + sec  


def global_to_galsec(global_coord) -> (Coordinate, Coordinate):
    # convert galactic/sector coord pair to global coordinate
    gal = Coordinate(int(global_coord.row / Constants.SECTOR_SIZE), int(global_coord.col / Constants.SECTOR_SIZE))
    sec = global_coord + (gal * -Constants.SECTOR_SIZE)
    return gal, sec


def calc_global_move(delta, gal_coord: Coordinate, sector_coord: Coordinate) -> Coordinate:
    gl = galsec_to_global(gal_coord, sector_coord)

    # debug_print('global1:', gl)
    # debug_print('delta:', delta)

    gl += delta
    gl.restrict_to_bounds(Coordinate(0, 0), Coordinate(Constants.GALAXY_SIZE * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE - 1,
                                                       Constants.GALAXY_SIZE * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE - 1))
    # debug_print('global2:', gl)
    # debug_print('global2gs:',  global_to_galsec(gl))

    return global_to_galsec(gl)


# noinspection PyAugmentAssignment
def tests():
    print('running tests')
    # check some basic coordinate conversions
    gal = Coordinate(1, 2)
    sec = Coordinate(3, 4)
    gl = galsec_to_global(gal, sec)
    assert gl.row == gal.row * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE + sec.row
    assert gl.col == gal.col * Constants.SECTOR_SIZE + sec.col
    g2, s2 = global_to_galsec(gl)
    assert gal == g2
```

ERROR: Type 'int' doesn't have expected attributes 'row', 'col'. Python seems to be indicating s2 is an int, but it was returned from global_to_galsec, which is annotated to return (Coordinate, Coordinate).  Note there is no error on the similar assert on the previous line.

```
    assert sec == s2

    gal = gal * 3
```

ERROR: Unresolved attribute reference 'row' for class 'int'
ERROR: Unresolved attribute reference 'col' for class 'int'

```
    assert gal.row == 3 and gal.col == 6
    sec += Coordinate(-1, -3)
    assert sec.row == 2 and sec.col == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tests()
```